# Why is Ne4 considered as an inaccuracy whereas it is one of very few moves which saves d3 pawn?

Tags: analysis, positional-play, knights, fork, brute-force

```
[FEN "r2q1rk1/1p3ppp/p4n2/2Pp4/1Pn5/P1Bp3P/3N2P1/R2QN2K b - - 4 21"]
```

With Black to move Ne4 is not even in top 5 moves and engine says its an inaccuracy. I know it considers fastest winning moves and positional moves too but Ne4 should be a move not an inaccuracy. Ne4 is also a forcing move with many threats.

Comment: Does ...Ne4 here really save black's d3 pawn? 1...Ne4 2.Nxe4 dxe4 3.Qg4 (threatening mate) g6 4.Qxe4, and the knight on c4 is under fire (as well as the d3 pawn).

Comment: And imagine your long face after 3...f5??. Insofar (remember you are an exchange up, so all +-1 pawn units are pointless) d4 is "better", since it takes off the wB, the last swindling chance.

Answer (score 7):

Calling it an "inaccuracy" is nothing more than the engine saying that it evaluates the position after one move to be a certain amount better than after another move. It doesn't necessarily mean a move is "bad".

Both d-pawns cannot be kept no matter what Black does. After 1...Ne4, if White plays Nxe4, the recapture will leave the c4 knight without a defender, and it doesn't have a lot of places to go. White can win the pawn on e4 and attack that knight. And the dark squares around the Black king are just a bit weak. Black is still winning though.

If instead Black plays ...d4, this forces some trades. Simplifying the position seems like a good idea for Black, since they are winning. Overall Stockfish likes this option better.

Here's a comparison showing what the next few moves might look like for each option:

```
[FEN "r2q1rk1/1p3ppp/p4n2/2Pp4/1Pn5/P1Bp3P/3N2P1/R2QN2K b - - 4 21"]

1...Ne4 (1...d4 2.Nxc4 dxc3 3.Qxd3 Qxd3 4.Nxd3 ) 2.Nxe4 dxe4 3.Qg4 g6 4.Qxe4 *
```

Comment: in your main line, what does white do after 4... d2?

Comment: @jf328 Seems like 5. Nd3 is the only option since 5. Qxc4 d1= Q wins another exchange for black